# Dit-on un ou une clope ?

Tags: genre, argot

Dit-on un ou une clope ?

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clope

Il me semble plus juste de dire une, mais j'ai entendu "un" à plusieurs reprises et cela m'a surpris. Quel est le bon genre ? Est-ce que les deux sont acceptés ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De mon expérience de locuteur natif, je n'ai jamais entendu "un clope" pour désigner une cigarette. Et pour cause, c'est une expression datée et j'ai grandi dans les années 90-2000. Comme l'indique le lien envoyé dans la question :

> In its original sense of "cigarette butt" clope was masculine; in the common modern sense both genders exist, but feminine is substantially more common.

Cette affirmation se confirme à l'usage, et on observe une explosion dans son utilisation depuis les années 2000, en témoigne [ce ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une%20clope%2C%20un%20clope&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20clope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20clope%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cune%20clope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20clope%3B%2Cc0):

[image: ngram clope]

Comme l'indique [son étymologie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/clope), le mot "clope" était à l'origine employé pour désigner **un** mégot, d'où le masculin. C'était de l'argot, et l'orthographe "clop" était alors également utilisée, avec selon toute vraisemblance la prononciation `[klo]`.

On peut donc conclure à une évolution du sens à l'usage, qui donne lieu à une évolution du genre du mot, phénomène [qui a souvent été observé dans l'Histoire de la langue française](https://www.rtl.fr/culture/arts-spectacles/quand-les-mots-changent-de-genre-7798375251).

Comment: Dans les années 70, le tabac était brun et cultivé sous le contrôle sourcilleux de l'état, héritage des poilus de la première guerre mondiale et, comme autre héritage, dans les règlements d'hygiène il y avait le vin rouge à table considéré comme un aliment avec le pain à volonté dans les restaurants comme dans les cantines. « Il avait son clope papier maïs constamment aux lèvres, qu'il rallumait de temps à autre. » https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=son+clope%2C+sa+clope&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3#, …

Comment: … les tabacs blonds "de Virginie" ayant envahi le marché dans les années 90 du fait qu"elles" (les donzelles pour garder l'argot d'avant) s'y sont mises, le clope a perdu sa virilité.

Comment: Anne Nivat dans "Haine et Déni", sorti début 2024, emploie systématiquement le masculin.

Comment: Same, Gen Y here but never heard of "un clope" in mine or younger generations. Anne Nivat is probably Gen X, or it's a regional or wanna-sound-working-class thing.